# How to enable LIMIT for DB2 on AS400 via JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, db2, limit, jtopen

I'd like to use the LIMIT clause to do paging on DB2. The DB2 is hosted on AS400 and I'm accessing it via JDBC over JTOpen.

In [Paging through result sets using LIMIT and OFFSET or ROWNUM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/limit_offset?lang=en) I learned that I can put DB2 into an MySql compatibility by calling

```
DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
```

This allows to use a LIMIT clause to do paging. Since my queries should run on MySql too this would be very helpull.

Unfortunaltely I did not find a way to enable this via JDBC and I'm not really sure this is supported at all on DB2 on AS400.

Hope somebody can shed some more light on this.

Comment: It's not possible on AS400 (System i) and you cannot enable it via JDBC on LUW. You can use one of the standard-compliant methods, such as the `ROW_NUMBER()` OLAP function, if it is available in your version of DB2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Is there some (ibm) documentation pointing this out?

Comment: Pointing what out? There are online information centres for each version of DB2, which you can find by googling for your particular version.

Comment: I found some blogs and entries here on so about the limit clause, but non of them clearly sates where this is suported.

Comment: Read about MySQL compatibility: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html

Comment: Note that the MySQL compatibility only works for the Linux/Unix/Windows version of DB2, and not the AS400 (or z/OS) version.

Comment: YES, MySQL compatibility is supported on IBM i (f.k.a. OS/400) by Zend (in cooperation with IBM) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1013084 for starters

Comment: @mustaccio That's what I was looking for. Feel free to add your comments as answer in order you get the credits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of LIMIT for DB2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885193/equivalent-of-limit-for-db2)

Comment: This is not a duplicate since it asks about *how* to enable the feature on different OS versions of DB2. The question is not asking about the LIMIT clause or how to achieve the same functionality on DB2.

Answer (score 0):

DB2/400 has native support for this out of the box (so do not fiddle with MySQL compatability!)

See [Equivalent of LIMIT for DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3885193/53897) for details.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to achieve LIMIT functionality. I'm asking about how to enable the feature.